# chrome developer tools - how do I get the network tab to stop timing after the page is done loading?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools to profile how my page is loading.

It shows a blue line after the DOM is loaded, then a red line after the page finishes completely loading (all the ads, etc).

However, there are apparently AJAX requests that continue to happen periodically in the background and then network tab keeps timing these -- the result is that the granularity and detail of the initial page load gets lost as the scale keeps being increased.

The DOM usually loads within 1 second and the page is usually done loading in under 8 seconds, and there are dozens of resources to closely examine within these first few seconds, but the network tab tracks events that happen 1 minute and 3 minutes and 8 minutes out, etc. which results in 99% of the horizontal space being dedicated to tracking things I don't care about and 99% of the things I care about being squished into about 1 horizontal pixel.

I would like the network tab to stop timing after it reaches the red line.

Answer (score 0):

There is a button in the upper right corner with the tooltip `Record Network Log`.  If this button is red, then recording will continue.  To stop the recording, press this button and toggle it to gray.  Just wait until you see the red line indicating that the page is done loading, then hit the button to stop the recording of network events.